# unity3d + UnitySocketIO + sails.js Error initializing handshake

Tags: unity-game-engine, sails.js

I'm using UnitySocketIO https://github.com/NetEase/UnitySocketIO
to connect to server on Sails.js Socket.IO. 
However, it errors out during the handshake with

```
socket Error: Error initializing handshake with http://192.168.0.104:1337/
```

Server Log:

```
 handshake error No cookie transmitted with socket.io connection.  Are you trying to access
 your Sails.js server via socket.io on a 3rd party domain?  If you're ok with losing users' 
session data, you can set `authorization: false` to disable cookie-checking. 
 Or you can send a JSONP request first from the client to the Sails.js server 
to get the cookie (be sure it's the same domain!!)
```

Help!

Comment: YEAAAH!!! On Sails is necessary to turn on the compatibility with socket io 0.9 client

Answer (score 0):

On Sails is necessary to turn on the compatibility with socket io 0.9 client